# Where to bind actions to a react component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is it bad practice to connect / bind actions (and for that matter, state) to a component in the same file in which you are defining said component? If so, is the suggested practice to create a container component (as outlined [here](https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact))? If that is the case and I want to drill props from a parent component to a child component that needs actions and state connected to it, and thus a container, how do I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If this said component is and will be the only one using the connected state and actions, no it is not a bad practice. Even this is not the case, you can connect multiple components to your store. But, wouldn't be easy to use a container component and pass your needed state parts and some of your action creators to the related child components?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { anAction, anotherAction } from "./actions/";

class ContainerApp extends React.Component {
  state = {
      maybeSomeLocalState: "",
  }

  render() {
    const { aState, anAction, anotherState, anotherAction } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Child
          aState={aState}
          anAction={anAction}
        />
        <Child2
          anotherState={anotherState}
          anotherAction={anotherAction}
        /
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  aState: state.aState,
  anotherState: state.anotherState,
});

export default connect( mapStateToProps, { anAction, anotherAction } )(ContainerApp);

const Child = (props) => (
  <div>
    <p>{props.aState.someValue}</p>
    <button onClick={props.anAction}>Do something</button>
  </div>
);

const Child2 = (props) => (
  <div>
    <p>{props.anotherState.someValue}</p>
    <button onClick={props.anotherAction}>Do another thing</button>
  </div>
);
```